# How to add TinyMce in angular 2?

Tags: angular, tinymce

I am new to angular 2 and trying to integrate tinymce in angular 2 but i am unable to use tinymce in my project. What i have done so far is i installed tinyMCe using bower in my project. All js files successfully added in my project. Then i added all references in layout page as below:

```
        <script src="~/lib/tinymce/tinymce.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/tinymce/themes/modern/theme.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.js"></script>
        <script src="~/lib/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.js"></script>
```

After this, i wrote component where i will use tineMce as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Routes, RouterModule } from "@angular/router";
import { NgForm } from "@angular/forms";
import Page = require("../../interfaces/iPage");
import PageService = require("../../services/page.service");
@Component({
    //no need for selector as it will be loaded via routing
    templateUrl: "/page/addEdit"
})


export class AddEditPageComponent implements OnInit {
    model = this.newModel();
    errorMessage: any;
    tinymce: any;

    constructor(private pageService: PageService.PageService) {
        this.tinymce.init({
            selector: "[tinymce]"
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }

    newModel(): Page.IPage {
        return {
            pageId: 0,
            pageName: null,
            title: null,
            content:null
        };
    }

    submitForm(form: NgForm) {
        debugger;
        this.pageService.save(this.model).subscribe(model => {
            this.model = this.newModel();
        },
            null);
    }


}
```

Then i add textArea on the html as below:

```
<textarea class="form-control" name="model.content" [tinymce]="tinymce" style="height: 300px" [(ngModel)]="model.content" placeholder="Description"></textarea>
```

My page is working fine when i don't use tinYmce but when i use tinyMCe, then this error comes on condole screen:
**Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'tinymce' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'.**

If i remove the textarea but don't remove tinYmce from init then this error comes:
**TypeError: Cannot read property 'init' of undefined**

I don't know what i am doing wrong. Kindly help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use `[tinymce]` on your textarea you have to declare it as a new input property.

```
import { Input } from '@angular/core';
@Component({....})
export class AppComponent {
  @Input() tinymce: string;
}
```

TinyMCE will be expecting a valid css selector and you might want to listen to some events in order to support live binding.

See below full implementation

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit, OnDestroy, Output, EventEmitter  } from '@angular/core';

declare var tinymce: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `
            <h3>Angular 2 Embedding TinyMCE</h3>
            <textarea>Start Typing</textarea>
            <p>{{ content }}</p>
            `
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit, OnDestroy { 

  @Output() onEditorKeyup = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public editor:any;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    tinymce.init({
      selector:'textarea',
      setup: editor => {
        this.editor = editor;
        editor.on('keyup', () => {
          const content = editor.getContent();
          this.onEditorKeyup.emit(content);
        })
      }
    });
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    tinymce.remove(this.editor);
  }

}
```

Note that in my case I have loaded tinymce from the cdn so i didn't have to setup the theme files.

```
<script src="//cdn.tinymce.com/4/tinymce.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Great job, Evans!

Comment: Thanks @Evans. It is running like a champ. You made my day. Thanks a lot.